# Square Matrix Traversal grouping adjacent cells with same values

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, traversal, pseudocode

Given a sample square matrix (0,1) as below:

```
0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 0
```

The desire output would be the number of groups of cells which have values equal to 1. e.g. the out put for the above matrix would be:

```
Group #1: (0,1), (0,2), (1,2), (2,3)
Group #2: (1,5), (2,5), (3,5), (4,5)
Group #3: (3,0), (4,1), (5,0)
Group #4: (5,3)
```

My current algorithm is as below:

```
for i = 0, i < matrix.dimension, i++
   for j = 0, j < matrix.dimension, j++
       if (i,j),(i,j+1),(i,j-1),(i-1,j),(i-1,j+1),(i-1,j-1),(i+1,j),(i+1,j+1),(i+1,j-1) = 1 
           push all pairs of i, j = 1 into a group
```

But then I am stuck at how to separate the `(2,3)` and `(2,5)` into 2 groups as they are still within a range of `(i+/-1, j+/-1)` if I traverse to the cell `(2,4)` for example. Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html

Comment: search for floodfill algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visualize this matrix as a graph. So at each co-ordinate `(x,y)`, this point is connected to 8 other points i.e

`(x+1, y)`,`(x+1,y-1)`,`(x+1,y+1)`,`(x,y+1)`,`(x,y-1)`,`(x-1,y)`,`(x-1,y+1)`,`(x-1,y-1)`.

So your point `(x,y)` will be connected to the above 8 points. Now you have a graph ready in front of you.

Now run `DFS` on this graph and you can easily find the set of co-ordinates with same values grouped together.

Hope this helps!